# Passport req.login doesn't create req.user

Tags: node.js, express, session, cookies, passport.js

i am trying to develop a login system with React,Node,Mysql,Express and Passport but i have encountered this problem. After calling req.login and passing it the userID, when i go to the route where i check for the req.user it says undefined. Here is my code for the server side.

```
const express = require("express");
const bodyParser = require("body-parser");
const cors = require("cors");
const app = express();
const session = require("express-session");
const { PORT = 8000 } = process.env;
const bcrypt = require("bcrypt");
const saltRounds = 10;
const cookieParser = require("cookie-parser");
const passport = require("passport");
var LocalStrategy = require('passport-local').Strategy;
const mysql = require("mysql");

/app.options("*", cors());
app.use(cors());
app.use(express.json()) // for parsing application/json
app.use(express.urlencoded({ extended: true })) // for parsing application/x-www-form-urlencoded
// app.use(cookieParser());

app.use(
  session({
    secret: "keyboard cat",
    resave: false,
    saveUninitialized: false

    // cookie: { secure: false }
  })
);




app.use(passport.initialize());
app.use(passport.session());

const connection = mysql.createConnection({
  host: "localhost",
  user: "root",
  password: "qwertyhnjkl",
  database: "login"
});

connection.connect(err => {
  if (err) {
    console.error("Error connection to database");

  }
    else console.log("Database connected");
});



app.get('/',function (req,res){
    console.log(req.user);
    console.log(req.isAuthenticated())
    res.send('hello world')
  });

app.post("/register", (req, res) => {
  const { name, username, email, password } = req.body;
  console.log(req.body);
  bcrypt.hash(password, saltRounds, function(err, hash) {
    connection.query(
      `insert into users(Name,Username,Email,Password) values('${name}','${username}','${email}','${hash}')`,
      function(error) {
        if (error) console.error(error);
      }
    );


    connection.query("SELECT LAST_INSERT_ID() as userID", (error,results,fields) =>
     {
      if (error) throw error;
      console.log(results)
      const userID = results[0].userID;
      console.log("userid in query: " + userID);
      req.login(userID, function(err) {
        if(err) res.send(err);

        else{
          console.log("req.user in req.login: " + req.user)
          console.log("isAuthenticated: "+ req.isAuthenticated())
          console.log(req.session )
          console.log('Logged in succesfully')
          res.send("Logged in succesfully");
        } 
      });
    });


  });
});
```

And this is how i handle the form in react:

```
submitRegister(event) {
    event.preventDefault();
    const data = this.state.data
    axios.post("http://localhost:8000/register", {
      name: data.name,
      username: data.username,
      email: data.email,
      password: data.password
    })
      .then(response => {
        console.log(response);
        if(response.data){
          console.log('Succesful signup');
          this.setState({ //redirect to login page
                        redirectTo: '/'
                    })
        }


      }).catch(error => {
        console.log("Sign up to server failed");
        console.log(error)
      });

  }
```

After i request the '/' of the server and check for the session in Application->Cookies->localhost there is no session.
The insertion is well done. I get the username email hashed password in my database. i get the right userID i even get the console.log in serialize function with the right userID(the last one introduced)

```
req.user in req.login: 47
isAuthenticated: true
Session {
  cookie:
   { path: '/',
     _expires: null,
     originalMaxAge: null,
     httpOnly: true },
  passport: { user: 47 } }
Logged in succesfully
serialize 47
```

This is what i get in the console when requesting the route /register from the server. Now when i go for localhost:8000 it says req.user is undefined and isAuthenticated false.

Comment: Check the insert query. Replace '${name}' with \`${name}`. Same for others.

Comment: The insertion is well done. I get the username email hashed password in my database. i get the right userID i even get the console.log in serialize function with the right userID(the last one introduced)

Answer (score 0):

Looks like cors() was the issue here. After removing it and using proxy in package.json solved the issue.